# How do you Uniquely Identify a line segment?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, 2d

I'm working on a problem to eliminate common line segments in a collection of Paths. Many of these paths share the same segment.

It seems that a 2D line would have some way to uniquely identity itself. Like a Key.

So a Line [(A,B), (C,D)] is the same as [(C,D), (A,B)]

Only Solution I could come up with is to sort the points.

This seems like it would be a common problem in Math or Graphics but the solution escapes me.

Comment: Do you generate these segments? How close can they be before they are "identical"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, this looks like a matter of an undirected graph (as opposed to a directed graph).

Sorting the points is one way to handle this:  it's a straightforward way to represent an unordered edge with a single, unambiguously selected value (it shouldn't matter what ordering you choose, as long as it is consistent for all possible segments).  You do need to ensure that you maintain this ordering as an invariant:  accidentally slipping in a mis-ordered edge could cause problems for anything that depends on the ordering.

However, mathematically speaking, undirected graphs are often defined as directed graphs with a symmetry property:  if (A,B) is an edge, then so is (B,A).  This suggests another way: ensure that you always store *both* (A,B) and (B,A).  Perhaps both segment orderings could have a link to any common data, and possibly a fast way to access one from the other.  (As with the sorted point method, you need to maintain this symmetry as an invariant.)

The best choice depends on your application.  If you're using your segments as a key, the sorting method might be best.  However, some applications are a better match for the symmetric method.  For example, the [doubly connected edge list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) is a data structure which represents each edge as two linked "half-edges", one in each direction.

---

Since you mention graphics, note that the doubly connected edge list is often used to represent the edges of 3-D polytopes.

Also, note the similarity to oriented triangles:  there are good, practical reasons for computer graphics to treat triangles as "one-sided", such that drawing a triangle visible from one side is distinct from drawing the same triangle visible from the other.  Like half-edges, this distinction is determined by the order of the vertices:  clockwise for one side, counterclockwise for the other.